# Why my Airflow REST API returns deleted dags

Tags: airflow, airflow-webserver, airflow-api

I have set of REST API in Airflow , and I have multiple dags inside my dag bag, but I have deleted one dag. After that, I restarted my Airflow scheduler and web server, but I get the deleted dag as a part of result.

API: (http://0.0.0.0:8080/api/v1/dags ) 
Airflow version : v2.1.0

How do I avoid getting deleted dags as a result from Airflow REST API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

only from  version 2.1.1

You can filter by "only_active" to your request

see [api reference](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/stable-rest-api-ref.html#tag/DAG)